# Java version compatibility for JNI library

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a .so library that is used by a jni library compiled with java 5 version. Is it ok to use java 6 to run this? Or should the .so library be recompiled with java 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly OK. Must be the same platform, of course.